# How to store molecules in memory?

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, variables, data-structures

I want to store molecules in memory. These can be simple molecules:

```
Methane (CH4)
C-H bond-length: 108.7 pm
H-H angle: 109 degrees
```

But also more complex molecules, like paracetamol (C8H9NO2):
[image: Paracetamol]

How can I store molecules in memory, including all bond-lengths and angles?

---

A good idea to store atom-structs in an array? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you describe various molecules in English? If so, you should be able to come up with a model that describes the same molecules in Objective C.

Comment: @Robinson Actually, people should be able to draw molecules themselves. I need to buffer them in memory so I can draw them, and serialize them for savage.

Comment: Do all molecules have fixed number of fields? (or) does the count of bond-length and angle varies with the complexity of the molecules?

Comment: I understand. It helps to explain the problem in words (as I did in my answer), then convert that to code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like some kind of graph data structure:

- A molecule has a set of atoms
- Atoms are linked by bonds:

  - A bond can be double, single or tripple
  - A bond has a length
  - A bond has an angle
- It's a cyclic graph (for instance, the example in the question has a ring of alternating single and double bonds)
- It's not a directed graph (if two atoms are bonded, it doesn't matter from which end you approach the bond)

Typically you'd store a graph as an array of nodes (atoms) and an array of edges (bonds). Nodes and edges would both be pointers to structs.

A node (atom) would store the element.

An edge (bond) would store the following fields:

- A pair of pointers to nodes
- The type of bond (double/single)
- The bond length and angle

Since it's not a directed graph, your data structure would consider an edge between A and B to be equivalent to an edge between B and A. That is, for a given pair of atoms, you'd expect your edge array to contain an edge from A to B and never from B to A.

Comment: A molecule is not a cyclic graph, it CAN be one though

Comment: @rano, right; it's not an acyclic graph. Any code that operates on a molecule graph needs to cope with cycles.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *atoms;` non-atomic atoms? hihi

Comment: It depends on the single molecule. How can you decide form the start if it will be cyclic or acyclic? (and for this reason you are right, you shall be able to cope with cycles, but you always will when you can't say anything more about the graph).

Comment: Triple bonds? They must have invented those after I did chemistry at school.

Comment: @Tim: the suspected maximal bond order is 6; triple bonds may be uncommon in nature, but they do occur outside the lab; quick googling didn't turn up a date for the first characterization of triple bonds, but for quadruple bonds, wikipedia suggests the date 1964

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're modeling a linked structure, it seems like a linked data structure would be the most appropriate representation. I'm afraid I'm not enough of a chemist to guess at all the data that would be interesting to store for each item though.

Offhand, it sounds a lot like a *very* slightly modified version of how you usually store a graph though -- nodes and links, with data associated with each. In a graph, the typical data associated with a link is the "cost" of that link, but in this case it sounds like you'd store a vector (angle and a length).

Comment: why a vector when you can have a struct? : P

Comment: @rano: sorry, I was using "vector" as it would be in physics, not really as it would be in programming. Whether you'd use a struct, `vector`, or something else to store it is a completely separate question.

Comment: @rano: vector is also a mathematical term, denoting angle and length.

Comment: @Paul Nathan sorry, my bad I came too fast to a conclusion ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) by Brad Larson, a supernice open source app for iPhone/iPod/iPad that inspired already many programmers. I guess he uses a standard data format for molecules that can inspire yours

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be doing any kind of computations on these molecules, or just drawing them? If you have any intention of doing any rigorous calculations, then I would not even try using Objective C. For best performance, you should store the angles, lengths, and connections in normal arrays, and do all the accounting necessary to keep track of what's what. These types of applications that use fancy data structures and such to hold the molecule info run very poorly if there is a lot of computation involved as well.

Answer (score 0):

A molecule in your posting is a descriptor like template of an instance of a concrete molecule (with different cartesian coordinates). Therefore, you need only one "molecule" for every possible number of molecule-type instances. Then, you need an array of coordinates from where you can extract which coordinates give one molecule. For this single descriptor, you should create data structures that allow you to access the values in the best way possible. Maybe a **vector** of (a,b,r,type)-Structs for bonds, a **vector** of (a,b,c,w,type) for angles etc.

Regards

rbo